# Cannot find suitable formatter for custom class object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, msmq

I'm writing messages to a Message Queue in C# as follows:

```
ObjectMsg objMsg = new ObjMsg(1,"ascii",20090807);
Message m = new Message();
m.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
m.body = objMsg;
queue.Send(m);
```

and I'm trying to read the messages as follows:

```
Message m = new Message()
m.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue("./pqueue");

m = mq.Recieve();
ObjMsg msg = (ObjMsg )m.Body;
```

However I'm getting an error message which says: "Cannot find a formatter capable of reading this message."

Comment: Feedback on my answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try reading the bodystream of the message like this:

```
Message m = new Message()
m.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue("./pqueue");

m = mq.Recieve();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(m.BodyStream);
string messageBody = "";
while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
{
    messageBody += sr.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` once instead of continually appending to a string. This is generally faster in my experience.

```
System.Messaging.Message[] messages = messageQueue.GetAllMessages();

foreach (System.Messaging.Message message in messages)
{
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(message.BodyStream);
    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```